Characterization of convex function on vector space
Reading the book Functional analysis and infinite-dimensional geometry by Fabian et. al, it is stated after Definition 8.2 that for a convex function $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $U$ is a convex subset of a vector space $V$, it is satisfied that the function
$$\phi(t)=\dfrac{f(x+ty)-f(x)}{t}$$
is increasing in $t$ for all $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ such that $x+ty \in U$.
In fact, it states that it is an equivalent definition for convexity, but I'm mainly interested in this implication.
Now, it is easy to see that this function $\phi$ satisfies that $\phi(s) \leq \phi(t)$ when $0<s<t$ or $s<t<0$ but I'm not able to prove it if $s<0<t$.
Maybe is just as easy as the previous cases but I've being struggling with it for a while and I don't see the way. Any ideas?

Hint: you'll need to start by writing $f(x)$ as a convex combination of $f(x + sy)$ and $f(x + ty)$, then apply Jensen's inequality.
